use of cookies is forcing all pages to be dynamic
I'm attempting to use cookies to set the app's theme. Users can choose their theme, which will create a cookie. When the server component RootLayout is rendered, it will fetch these cookies and apply the selected theme.
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const cookie = cookies();
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      data-theme-mode={cookie.get("theme-mode")?.value ?? "dark"}
      data-theme-color={cookie.get("theme-color")?.value ?? "default"}
    >
      <body className={`antialiased bg-background text-foreground dark`}>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The main goal of this approach is to avoid the "flash-bang" effect or any sudden changes when the theme transitions from the default to the user's selected theme.
However, the downside of setting this in the RootLayout component is that it causes all pages to be dynamically rendered.
So my question is: Is this acceptable? If not, what is the best way to set a user-defined theme while also preventing theme "flashes"?

React Context is one of the best ways to implement a theme switcher: https://medium.com/@riteshbhagat/implementing-theme-in-react-using-context-api-196149967c9d

I've already tried what you are suggesting. The problem is that this causes a "flash" if the user's selected theme is different than the default that is rendered on the server.
